# What's wrong with my function for finding highest prime factor?

Tags: php, math, primes

```
function find_highest_prime_factor($n)
{
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++) 
    {   
        if (bcmod($n, $i) == 0) //its a factor
        {
            return max($i, find_highest_prime_factor(bcdiv($n,$i)));
        }
    }
    if ($i == $n)
    {
        return $n; //it's prime if it made it through that loop
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: This is the correct answer, my bad!

Comment: Can you give us an example input?

Comment: if `($i == $n)` is redundant, its always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the final if statement otherwise if `$i!=sqrt($n)` because sqrt($n) is not an integer you have an undefined return value

```
function find_highest_prime_factor($n){
  for ($i = 2; $i <= sqrt($n); $i++) //sqrt(n) is the upperbound
  {
       if (bcmod($n, $i) == 0) //its a factor
       {
          return max($i, find_highest_prime_factor(bcdiv($n,$i)));
       }
   }
   return $n; //it's prime if it made it through that loop
 }
```

Comment: Still not getting the highest prime though.. Doesn't seem to make a difference in the answer with the one I was doing

Comment: This is even better: if it makes it through that first loop, it has to be prime, no need to test again....

Comment: Which answer are you trying because this version fixed the error for 14

Comment: Try 600851475143, it still yields only 6857 which is incorrect (not the highest)

Comment: D'oh, that is correct.  Just looked too small to be true :).. In fact my original function was correct.. I thought it waswrong because I entered the wrong confirmation code on the site.

Comment: Nothing solved it.. it was right to begin with.  Downvoting myself now

Comment: The sqrt version wasn't because of the test at the end... That final test is comletely unnecessary. Also your current version is inefficient because it goes paste the sqrt factor test wasting cycles.

Comment: I notice that your program will keep starting over dividing by 2, even if you've already factored out all the smaller primes.  In this case, you might try an inner loop instead of the recursion you have:  keep dividing by each factor until it *doesn't* work, then go on to the next.

Answer (score 1):

Line 11 should be:

```
if ($i == ceil(sqrt($n)))
```

Comment: You sqrt optimization was fine, my initial reply was wrong.  Go back to your original code and make the change above, all will be good.  Link to OP's original code, with my change: http://codepad.viper-7.com/1aODAo

Answer (score 0):

Starting at 2 and stepping by 1 is inefficient.  At least check 2 separately and then loop from 3 stepping 2 each time.  Using a 2-4 wheel would be even faster.

When you recurse your code starts again at trial factor 2.  It would be better to pass a second parameter holding the factor you have reached so far.  Then the recursion wouldn't have go back over old factors that have already been tested.